# Determine best flight path

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, shortest-path

I work for an aerial surveying company. I have a powerline dataset for an entire state that we need to survey. The lines in the dataset are not always connected. I need to determine an optimum flight plan that will minimize travel time and flying over a line more than once. I have 1 starting point (our office). I looked into a network analyst but as the lines are not connected, I cannot use this feature. Someone suggested connecting the lines manually, but there are around 500 line features in the dataset.

I recently downloaded ArcGIS 10.3.1 with all of the extensions.

Comment: How about connecting them?

Comment: What tools do you have available? (i.e. ArcGIS 10.2, what license, extensions)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your Route Analysis is in ArcGIS Network Analyst, if you are looking to fly over once then try connecting the powerlines as a geometric network.

Using Editor you can add segments that connect to the current lines you have now to make an entirely traversable network.

Just be sure to notate in the attributes that a line segment had been user added and not a part of the original dataset.

Comment: This will do the job, but rather than editing the existing power line dataset, make a copy!

Comment: I have over 500 features in this dataset, is there an automatic way to connect them or another way to complete the type of analysis I am looking for?